# Ubuntu installed over Windows10 in UEFI - can't see windows

Tags: 16.04, windows, boot-repair

Ok I have a somehow new computer that supports UEFI. I had Windows 10 installed for a month now, but wanted to install ubuntu (16+). On previous computers installation of ubuntu after windows was problemless and I had grub showing me options to boot either windows or ubuntu. Now during Ubuntu installation it displayed a warning saying that it can render my other OS unbootable - which I ignored because I have many times done this installation. Apparently something changed due to UEFI and my windows wasn't shown on Grub list.

I tried Boot-repair from bootable USB stick but it just (i think) removed grub and I cant boot anything with that pc for this moment.

Please what can I do to get my windows back without the need to reinstall it? I have it set pretty well so I don't want to have to install everything again. Ideally I would also want to keep my installed Ubuntu but thats a lower priority for me.

Can someone please help me? I will be watching this thread closely so if you want me to provide any more information then just ask.

Best regards
Marcin

Comment: Post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info If newer Windows 8 or 10, it uses fast start up or always on hibernation. Then Linux NTFS driver does not see Windows. Or you must have fast start up off with newer Windows. And if dual booting you do not choose any of the full drive install options. Always best to partition in advance and use Something Else install option.

Comment: http://paste2.org/yjKYU0JK
This is the paste bin. However my system is Windows10 not Windows 8, and i just ran it not on april 26. Does this make sense? EDIT. Ok i can see even the names of partitions are correct so it has to be my pc

Comment: Both Windows & Ubuntu are installed in BIOS boot on MBR partitioned drive. Windows only boots from MBR with BIOS, so you cannot boot with UEFI unless you totally reinstall Windows. But it shows UEFI Secure Boot may be on, and you booted Boot-Repair in UEFI mode. As Boot-Repair says you must turn off Secure Boot, as BIOS boot is not a Secure boot option. And with installs in BIOS mode always boot in BIOS mode.

Comment: OK now when i boot my pc i Get something like "error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found. Entering rescude mode... According to what you say and what I can conclude is that I had normal bios MBR installation for both windows and linux and that I removed my grub using boot-repair. So what I need to do now is 1. Install grub again 2. Make it point to both windows and ubuntu. AM i right? How do I do it?

Comment: Boot Boot-Repair in BIOS mode and have it reinstall grub to MBR. If still errors use the advanced mode and the full uninstall/reinstall of grub. Just make sure Internet is working as it will download a new copy of the full grub installer.

Comment: I had a problem that internet was not working when i booted from boot-repair live usb. It works fine when i do Ubuntu live cd boot. I will try to fix this issue with the Boot-repair but do you think i can do this from ubuntu live cd? I tried this http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd but when i reached the grub-install /dev/sda it said "The program 'grub-install' can be found in the following packages:" and it was just the same as in this thread (ctrl+f the line i pasted)  https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1393066.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46768/discussion-between-user209060-and-oldfred).

Comment: OK i solved my issue. I think every such issue is individual depending on what steps you made to mess your booting. I will wait 24h for oldfred to make his official answer describing best what has happened here and I will  make it the answer to the problem. If he won't then I will post answer myself describing the best I can what happened here, so other ppl can benefit from it

Comment: Thread you linked to was from 2010, and used a chroot for a full reinstall of grub. Boot-Repair semi-automates that. But not sure if the Boot-Repair live repair disk is updated to newest version of Lubuntu yet. Often better to just add Boot-Repair to standard Ubuntu live installer you use. If you just reinstalled existing package, that may also work if package not yet housecleaned and current version.